# Setting null value to a custom date field via script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am trying to assign `null` value to a custom date field in SuiteScript 2.0 scheduled script, but the system is not accepting it.

So far I tried assigning `null`, `''`,`""`, `undefined` to the field to no avail.
Here is the piece of the script:

```
var dtVendor = '';
PO_Data.setValue({
   fieldId: 'custbody1', 
   value : dtVendor
});
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestion/idea.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `setText`.

```
var dtVendor = '';
PO_Data.setText({
   fieldId: 'custbody1', 
   text : dtVendor
});
```

Comment: I tried setText but getting the error 'Field must contain a value.'

Answer (score 0):

setText won't work on a date field, I have tried the below from a workflow action and it blanks the date out.

```
    // set fields originally from workflow
            record.submitFields({
              type: newRecord.type,
              id: newRecord.id,
              values: {
                       'custrecord_bsb_date' : null,                             
                      }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting a date value in SS2.0 you will use null. I think you might be forgetting to save the record after the change?

PO_Data.setValue('custbody1',null);
PO_Data.save();